# Create / Commands in Cogs with nextcord?

Tags: python, discord, nextcord

Im not sure if im doing this wrong or not but im having to wait quite a while for the command to show up

```
@slash_command(name="somename", description="somediscription", guild_ids=[id])
async def verify(self, interaction:Interaction):
pass
```

(this is my first stackoverflow post so im sorry if i dont do it entirely right)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the updated version of slash commands with these commands:
`pip uninstall nextcord`
`pip install git+https://github.com/alentoghostflame/nextcord@slash_fixes`

Then add this code underneath `bot.load_extension`, wherever you load your cog:

```py
for guild_id in TESTING_GUILD_IDS:
    guild = bot.get_guild(guild_id)
    await guild.rollout_application_commands()
```

where `TESTING_GUILD_IDS` is your list of guild ids.

Comment: now im getting a TypeError `TypeError: test() takes from 0 to 1 positional arguments but 2 were given`

Comment: never mind i forgot to pass in self thank you so much this helped a lot :)

Comment: Glad I could help! Could you please verify this answer?